# Gtk2Hs make its own Signal (or Event)

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk2hs

I'm trying to create a program with Gtk2Hs and Haskell and I wonder if it is possible to create a new signal with Gtk.

For example I created a **hBox** containing a **button** and a **text entry**. This component can be added at differents places in the window and I would like to trigger some action when the button is pressed or when the entry is edited.

Is it possible to create and force the widget (the hBox?) to emit a custom `my_own_signal` with something like :

```
onbuttonPressed button $ do emit my_own_signal
onEntryActivate entry $ do emit my_own_signal
```

which could be captured by making a

```
on hbox my_own_signal $ do somethings
```

or

```
on my_widget my_own_signal $ do somethings
```

This way I could have a "global" signal for my widget/hbox

I'm using GHC 7.4.1 and Gtk2Hs 0.12.3

Comment: Why do you want to create your own signal? Couldn't you just connect handlers to the signals that are already provided?

Comment: Looking at the docs, [Signal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/glib-0.13.0.7/docs/System-Glib-Signals.html#t:Signal) has its constructor exported... can you formulate your "attaching a new callback to the signal" operation as `Bool -> object -> handler -> IO (ConnectId object)`? (the `Bool` is for before/after).